# Eclipse hover and documentation dialogs have a dark background

Tags: linux, eclipse, colors, themes

I would like to start using Eclipse in place of Netbeans. However, it seems to be that even the most basic things like setting the colours are very difficult to do.

I really can not figure out how to have a decent colour in both tooltips and documentation dialogs. Currently, they are like you can see here:

[image: Documentation]
[image: Hover]

As you can see in the following image, I have already set the documentation background to white, but to no avail. I also tried different colours, nothing changes.
[image]

Following some advices in an other answer, I tried modifying my theme tooltip colour, but is already as they suggest me to edit it.

```
/usr/share/themes/Numix-ArchBlue/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

[image: gtkrc]

Other settings are like these:

[image]

I am on `Arch` with `xfce4-session 4.12.1 (Xfce 4.12)` and `Numix-ArchBlue` as theme.

Any idea about what I shall do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however I use the Greybird theme on a Debian testing machine.

I managed to solve it by doing the following:

1. Edit `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk-contained.css`
   Particularly, set the `tooltip` `background` and `foreground` colors as follows:

   `background-color: #ffffff;`

   `color: black;`

This sets the background color to white and the foreground (font) color to black.

The tooltip section of the CSS file looks like this:
[The modified tooltip section of the gtk-contained.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJo5P.png)

2. I did the same for `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk-contained-dark.css`

The end result in Eclipse is depicted below:
[Eclipse tooltip after editing the CSS files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ7sE.png)

Maybe for the Numix theme, this would be of help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/765909/tweaking-newer-gtk3-themes

Good luck!

Kind regards,
Nikolay